Can you set relative source of all properties within a control instead of setting it inline on property?
I am starting to get a hang of all this binding and WPF stuff.  One thing I am stuck on is the following.  I have a User control here and I want to bind the properties (custom dependency properties) with data from other classes, or in this case the same one.  I am doing this simply because I have different user controls for different situations but using the same user control.
Everything currently works as such.  Also if I do not do any binding the dependency properties work just fine.  Just seeing if I can come up with a cleaner solution so I do not have to keep typing this relative source every time.
Calibration Control is a Custom User Control and the Calibration Subpage is set to local but it will be other classes as well.
<components:CalibrationControl
    Grid.Row="0"
    BarMax="{Binding ViewModel.Throttle1.BarMax, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:CalibrationSubpage}}"
    BarMin="{Binding ViewModel.Throttle1.BarMin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:CalibrationSubpage}}"
    BarValue="{Binding ViewModel.Throttle1.BarValue,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:CalibrationSubpage}}"
    DeadZone="0"
    IsEnabled="True"
    Panel="{Binding ViewModel.Throttle1.Panel,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:CalibrationSubpage}}" />```


I would like to know if I can make an easier way to do this.


The Binding Paths starting with ViewModel. indicate that the actual source object of those Bindings is a view model. The view model instance should be passed to the control via its DataContext property, then the Bindings would simply look like BarMax="{Binding Throttle1.BarMax}" (where the DataContext provides the default source object).

you can narrow down control's DataContext and then bind each property declaring only Path:
<components:CalibrationControl
    Grid.Row="0"
    DataContext="{Binding ViewModel.Throttle1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:CalibrationSubpage}}"
    BarMax="{Binding BarMax}"
    BarMin="{Binding BarMin}"
    BarValue="{Binding BarValue}"
    DeadZone="0"
    IsEnabled="True"
    Panel="{Binding Panel}" />

